# Check if application is installed on Nokia devices?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, nokia

I try to check if application is installed on the device. In BlackBerry I can do it with

```
CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("applicationName");
```

How can I do it on the Nokia device?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code:

```
String platform = System.getProperty("microedition.platform");
boolean isNokia = false;

if (platform != null) {
  platform = platform.toLowerCase();
  isNokia = platform.indexOf("nokia") >= 0;
}
```

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/System_property_microedition.platform_values_for_Symbian_devices

Comment: thank.. but this no answer for my question.. I ask if i want to know if for example i want to check if gogle maps is installes on my device. how can i check that?

Comment: You can not. Midlet application management service does not have a method for this.